# Celery, Dynamically adding periodic task

Tags: celery

https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#entries mentions `add_periodic_task`

I'm not getting what is `test.s and test.s('hello')` and not just `test('hello')`

```
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab

app = Celery()

@app.on_after_configure.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
    # Calls test('hello') every 10 seconds.
    sender.add_periodic_task(10.0, test.s('hello'), name='add every 10')

    # Calls test('world') every 30 seconds
    sender.add_periodic_task(30.0, test.s('world'), expires=10)

    # Executes every Monday morning at 7:30 a.m.
    sender.add_periodic_task(
        crontab(hour=7, minute=30, day_of_week=1),
        test.s('Happy Mondays!'),
    )

@app.task
def test(arg):
    print(arg)
```

and what would be the `sender`? I'd liket call `add_periodic_task` outside of `@app.on_after_configure.connect`

Answer (score 1):

`.s()` is the task signature - think of it as placeholder for running a task - `test('hello')` would invoke your task immediately, which is not what you would want when you just want to instruct Celery to call the task periodically in `setup_periodic_tasks`.

Comment: ah make sense, I added another question to OP, can you take a look at it too?